# Filter out built-in wp_nav_menu classes but keep custom class

Tags: menus

Im trying to remove / filter our all the classes from the wp_nav_menu, EXCEPT the custom ones that i insert (in the "CSS Classes (optional)" field) when creating the menu in the admin.

I found a function that removes EVERYTHING, but thats no good

anybody got any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: See this thread for the most adequate function:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/removing-all-classes-from-nav-menu-except-current-menu-item-and-current-menu-par

Answer (score 6):

One of the darker corners of the code. :) Here is my take:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'discard_menu_classes', 10, 2);

function discard_menu_classes($classes, $item) {

    return (array)get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true );
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice one. Now if I could just get the current-menu-item back!

Comment: @N2Mystic well you only need to check incoming `$classes` for it and keep it, instead of returning retrieved array only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to answer.

The function that responsible to generate classes for menu items is `_wp_menu_item_classes_by_context` in the file `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`. You can dig there to see what classes it generate, so you can strip it out in `nav_menu_css_class` filter.

I found that every classes that automatically generated started with `menu-item` class. So, in the filter I loop the classes array until found that class.

This is my code:

```
function my_nav_menu_css_class($classes) {
    $custom_classes = array();
    foreach($classes as $class) {
        if($class=='menu-item') return $custom_classes;
        $custom_classes[] = $class;
    }
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_nav_menu_css_class');
```