# Removing all classes from nav_menu except current-menu-item and current-menu-parent

Tags: theme-development

Thanks to [Rarst's clever answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21355/filter-out-built-in-wp-nav-menu-classes-but-keep-custom-class), I'm succesfully using these bits to remove the classes from the custom menu markup...

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'discard_menu_classes', 10, 2);

function discard_menu_classes($classes, $item) {
    return (array)get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true );
    }
```

However, I do need the current-menu-item and current-menu-parent classes when I'm viewing a current page element or a child of a current-menu-item.

Is it possible to add these without all the extra classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can filter out all the classes but the ones you want.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'discard_menu_classes', 10, 2);

function discard_menu_classes($classes, $item) {
    $classes = array_filter( 
        $classes, 
        create_function( '$class', 
                 'return in_array( $class, 
                      array( "current-menu-item", "current-menu-parent" ) );' )
        );
    return array_merge(
        $classes,
        (array)get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true )
        );
    }
```

Comment: I'd write out code (not that much of it for this) rather than creating function.